# Linq query(Filter, where, if)

Tags: c#, linq, postgresql-9.3

I want to put the variables that are filled in question in the where condition. How can I do with Linq?

Running query;

```
  query = db.Kisi.Where(item => item.KAYITTIPI == registerType)
           .Where(item => item.ADI.Contains(name))
           .Where(item => item.SOYADI.Contains(surname))
           .Where(item => item.UNVAN.Contains(title))
           .OrderBy(item => item.ID)
           .Skip(page)
           .Take(top)
           .ToList();
```

I want to do;

```
var query = db.Kisi.Where(item => item.KAYITTIPI == registerType)
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                {
                   .Where(item => item.ADI.Contains(name))
                }
                 else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(surname))
                {
                    .Where(item => item.SOYADI.Contains(surname))
                }

                 .Where(item => item.UNVAN.Contains(title))
                 .OrderBy(item => item.ID)
                 .Skip(page)
                 .Take(top)
                 .ToList();
```

Error;

```
State Error CS0103 The name 'Where' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compose your LINQ query in separate statements and they won't be executed until you call `ToList`:

```
IQueryable<Kisi> query = db.Kisi.Where(item => item.KAYITTIPI == registerType);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
   query = query.Where(item => item.ADI.Contains(name))
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(surname))
{
    query = query.Where(item => item.SOYADI.Contains(surname))
}

var result = query.Where(item => item.UNVAN.Contains(title))
                  .OrderBy(item => item.ID)
                  .Skip(page)
                  .Take(top)
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put all your expressions in one boolean expression?

```
var result = db.Kisi.Where(item => (item.KAYITTIPI == registerType)
    && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) || item.ADI.Contains(name))
    && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(surname) || item.SOYADI.Contains(surname))
    && item.UNVAN.Contains(title))
    .OrderBy(...)
    .Skip(...)
    .Take(...);
```